# How to create an array field in a json file using groovy GStringTemplateEngine

Tags: json, groovy

I want to create the following json:

```
{
"reviewers": [
    {
      "user": { 
        "name": "a"
      }
    },
    {
        "user": {
          "name": "b"
      }
    },
    {
        "user": {
          "name": "c"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

using:

```
users= ["a", "b", "c"]
def binding = [
        arr : users
]

def f = new File(templateFileName)
def engine = new groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine()
def template = engine.createTemplate(f).make(binding)
println template.toString()
```

I tried several variations for the template and ended with:

```
{
"reviewers": [
    <%  arr.each { out <<
  """ {
        "user": {
          "name": "${it}"
        }
},"""
} %>
]
}
```

this results in:

```
    {
  "reviewers": [
     {
        "user": {
          "name": "a"
        }
}, {
        "user": {
          "name": "b"
        }
}, {
        "user": {
          "name": "c"
        }
},// <-- illegal comma
]
}
```

the problem is with the last entry which adds a redundant comma (which cause the json to be illegal)
is there a way do create it more elegantly so the last entry would not include the illegal comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to build it easily using `JsonBuilder`

```
def users= ["a", "b", "c"]
def jsonBuilder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder() 
jsonBuilder { reviewers users.collect { u ->
    return { user { name (u) } }
  }
}
println(jsonBuilder.toPrettyString())​
```

Quickly can be tried the above example online <kbd>[Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5070734556659712)</kbd>

#### Rao has the answer, but wrapping it as a template would look like:

```
def tpl = '''<%=
def jsonBuilder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder() 
jsonBuilder {
    reviewers users.collect { u ->
        { -> user { name (u) } }
    }
}
jsonBuilder.toPrettyString()
%>'''

users= ["a", "b", "c"]
def binding = [
    users : users
]

def engine = new groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine()
def template = engine.createTemplate(tpl).make(binding)
println template.toString()
```

Comment: Thanks @Rao, it is indeed elegant, but I prefer to use a template json file. is there a way to combine this code inside a template?

Comment: Just put @Rao's code inside `<%= ... %>` tags (and replace `println(jsonBuilder.toPrettyString())​` with `jsonBuilder.toPrettyString()`) then pass the users into the binding as you have in the question, and render the template

Comment: thanks @tim_yates, I suggest to add your comment to Rao's answer, as it would be the solution.

Comment: @tim_yates, it is absolutely fine. Of course, you could add new answer as well :)

Comment: @Rao naaah, you got it...  Would feel like poaching ;-)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative would be to process each array element with a subtemplate (the second triple quoted text you pasted) using `collect` instead of `each`. Next, all elements are joined using `,\n`, like this

```
tpl = '''{
"reviewers": [
    <%  out << arr.collect {
  """ {
    "user": {
      "name": "${it}"
    }
}"""
}.join(',\\n') %>
]
}
'''

users= ["a", "b", "c"]
def binding = [
    arr : users
]

def engine = new groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine()
def template = engine.createTemplate(tpl).make(binding)
println template.toString()
```

Notice that `out` is given the result of the whole computation and not during each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another option for creating the template without using JsonBuilder.

In this case I used join(,) and therefore there was no redundant comma character at the end. (it also work as an inner part of a larger json file)

```
{"reviewers": [
    <%
     out << pullReqReviewers.collect { 
             "{ \"user\": { \"name\": \"${it}\"} } "
           }.join(',')
    %>
]}
```